# How to access iframe's body and get its text value? without JQUERY

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, getelementbyid, formidable

I'm using formidable plugin to upload an image to node server, after upload is done, it returns an iframe with the corresponding message of success and its path.

I would like to retrieve this message to a string variable at client side (browser).

[image: Iframe object]

The above object is taken using `var tempPath=document.getElementById('imho_id');`

I've tried `document.getElementById('imho_id').innerHTML;` but with no success.

My confusion here is the #document part and the access to  style object, i appreciate if someone could help and also briefly explain the logic of accessing document or #document.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I assume you want to access it in the browser, don't you? Or do you need to process in NodeJS on the server?

Comment: @yunzen document.getElementById suggests it is not on the backend

Comment: Hey @yunzen, yes i would like to access at client side (browser).

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. ***[Do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+access+content+iframe+site:stackoverflow.com)***, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: `console.log(document.querySelector('imho_id').contentDocument.querySelector('pre').textContent)`

Comment: This has a point! but the console error is -> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentDocument' of null"